# How to return from preference screen to main activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, settings, preferences, android-preferences

I have one main activity and one preferenceActivity. On my first activity I call menu and go on preferenceActivity by calling startActivityForResult.

```
                case R.id.settings:
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class), LAUNCH_SETTINGS);
                return true;
```

Then I change my settings and want to return on main activity and see main activity with new settings applyed. In onPause() method do following (as I right understand this method will be called when I press back button, right?)

```
   @Override
     protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
         finish();
     }
```

On main activity

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == LAUNCH_SETTINGS) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                new RefreshList().execute(ACTION_SELECT);
                Log.d(TAG, "On activity result");
            }
        }
    }
```

But my acyncTask do not called and log not printed. How correctly I can do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> On my first activity I call menu and go on preferenceActivity by calling startActivityForResult.

Using `startActivityForResult()` with a `PreferenceActivity` is rather unusual. `PreferenceActivity` is designed to be used with `startActivity()`. If the one starting the `PreferenceActivity` cares about preference changes, it should register a preference change listener with the `SharedPreferences` object.

> Then I change my settings and want to return on main activity and see main activity with new settings applyed.

I recommend that you use a `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` instead. Or, simply re-read the preferences you care about in the original activity's `onStart()` or `onResume()` method.

> In onPause() method do following (as I right understand this method will be called when I press back button, right?)

No, that will not work. `onPause()` is too late to call `setResult()`.