# Update calling activity after PreferenceScreen close?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, updating, start-activity

I have an activity A from where I invoke a PreferenceAvtivity P via a normal startActivity.
The user can update some settings there, and after the P is closed, activity A should update itself to get the new settings.

Now I've read here [How to return from preference screen to main activity?](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936536/how-to-return-from-preference-screen-to-main-activity&ei=oyK3UMrKN82AhQekhYGYAg&usg=AFQjCNGKSQLdlHVXVH_h0P2kJx-qtAnTjw) that you should not/must not open the preferences via startActivityForResult, but rather implement an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in activity A.

My problem here is, the updating task in activity A might be a heavy one, and when activity A listens to PreferenceChanges, it updates whenever something was changed in P.

--> I need A to update only once, this is after P is closed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: Read relevant preferences in onResume() of activity A.

Edit: Great nick btw

Comment: That works, but it would mean that the update also happens when A is interrupted by something else, let's say a call? Which I would like to avoid (if possible) edit: lol, thx xD

Comment: then maybe only set a flag in `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` and only update in onResume if e.g. `boolean prefsUpdated` is set?

Comment: Yes, maybe something like that. Either way, the onResume tip solved the situation (...never mind of the update after a call or so) Thanks!